# Find an attribute that contains a ceratin string and modifying its Value in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, contains

I'm trying to find the first attribute in an xml file that contains the string "name" (case insensitve) in it and then change its value.

Here is an example of my xmls

```
//XML 1
<CtApproachTypes  
 DataclassId="1992A9CE-B048-4676-BFD4-FD81F1A65401"  
 EntityId="1992A9CE-B048-4676-BFD4-FD81F1A65401"  
 Name="PAR"  
 Remark="No Remarks"></CT_ApproachTypes> 

//XML 2
<MiMissions  
 DataclassId="C196A66B-4FA1-461C-9EEF-95A4F2085051"  
 EntityId="C196A66B-4FA1-461C-9EEF-95A4F2085051"  
 MissionName="Standard" 
 Visib="1"></MiMissions> 

//XML 3
<StSituations  
 DataclassId="679FAC3C-C9EF-41FD-9A13-957915605F01"  
 EntityId="679FAC3C-C9EF-41FD-9A13-957915605F01"  
 Sname="Standard"  
 Status="C"  
 Template="1"></StSituations>
```

I wanna be able to modify the values of "Name", "MissionName", "Sname", and print them out to console

**EDIT**
here is my code

```
        public void updateXmlFile(string strFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(strFileName);

            string newValue = GetUniqueKey();

            XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("@*"); 
            IEnumerable<XmlNode> filteredList= list.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(item=>item.Value.ToLower().Contains("name"));

            foreach (XmlNode n in filteredList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NODES ARE : {0}", n);
            }
                doc.Save(strFileName);

        }
        catch (XmlException xex) { Console.WriteLine(xex); }

    }
```

This didn't print out anything and I need still to modify the original value with the string newValue

Comment: look at the answers to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506730/linq-to-xml-get-the-next-node-of-the-same-name , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333751/linq-to-xml-select-all-attributes-and-their-values-for-a-given-node

Comment: @Matt: Could you help me more. I couldn't relate the answers to my problem.

Comment: I'm guessing the mistakes in your XML are just typos?

Comment: oh! Yes they are I don't know how that happened, must be the editor somehow.I'll just correct them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) object, because it is easy to query with linq. It's in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace and assembly.

```
public void updateXmlFile(string strFileName)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(strFileName);

    var nameAttributes = from el in xDoc.Root.Elements()
                         from attr in el.Attributes()
                         where attr.Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains("name")
                         select attr;

    foreach (var attribute in nameAttributes)
    {
        attribute.Value = "newValue";
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
    }

    xDoc.Save(strFileName);
}
```

**Update**

This is the output, given the XML in your example if it is saved into a single file:

```
Name: newValue
MissionName: newValue
Sname: newValue
```

Comment: Thanks Matt that's also a good way to query (I was actually trying to solve it using XDocument)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is first select all XML attributes, then use LINQ to select all attributes containing 'Name'.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
...
XmlNodeList list = document.SelectNodes("@*");
IEnumerable<XmlNode> filteredList= list.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(item=>item.Value.ToLower().Contains("name"));
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Edit:

Reda, you were absolutely right, I made some mistakes. This code worked on my machine ;-) I added comments where I altered your code.

```
    public void updateXmlFile(string strFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(strFileName);

            string newValue = GetUniqueKey();

            XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//@*"); // Forgot the slashes here...
            IEnumerable<XmlNode> filteredList = list.Cast<XmlNode>().
                Where(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains("name")); // Name property instead of Value

            foreach (XmlNode n in filteredList)
            {
                n.Value = newValue; // Setting the value.
                Console.WriteLine("FILTERED NODES ARE : {0}", n.Value);
            }

            doc.Save(strFileName);

        }
        catch (XmlException xex) { Console.WriteLine(xex); }

    }
```

Comment: @Jeroen: I tried to print out the 'n' alone, the output was System.Xml.XmlAttribute! In my first post the example shows 3 seperate XMLs and not Nodes of the same XML, I guess thatÄs why I'm getting such output

Comment: Is that something you didn't expect? The nodes are of type 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute', so that is what gets printed.

Comment: then why are the attributes in the XMLs not changed?

Comment: Oh! I feel so stupid now. I was checking the old XMLs :S The code works thanks a lot Jeroen. Can I only change the first attribute that cotains the string name?

Comment: Yes, replace the Where method call with a First method call: XmlNode firstNode = list.Cast<XmlNode>().
                First(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains("name"));

Comment: Thanks again I really appreciate the quick answer